# check the log in if user or admin with php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check if the one who logged in is user or admin, I created a column in my DB named 'pin' and put the value whether 0 or 1.
if the pin in 0 so the logged in is an admin and user otherwise.
here is my code but it didn't work with me, please help, I'm totally beginner

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ID, password FROM facultymember ".
    "WHERE password='$password' AND ID='$ID'", $connection);
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT pin FROM facultymember ".
    "WHERE password='$password' AND ID='$ID'", $connection);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2);
$check = $row2['pin'];
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1 && $check == 1) {
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$ID; // Initializing Session
    header("location: homeFM.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page

}
else if($rows == 1 && $check == 0) {
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$ID; // Initializing Session
    header("location: homeA.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
} else {
    $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
}
```

Comment: *"but it didn't work with me"* - Meaning?

Comment: the page of homeFM.php opens on each situation, for admin and user

Comment: Why don't you query for the `pin` with the first query? Why run a completely different one?

Comment: is it wrong to do this?

Comment: You don't need to select the `ID, password` you already have that because they are the variables. Passwords should be hashed, hopefully these values have been sanatized.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i rewrote what you have to try and make sense of it for you, with comments.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ID, password, pin FROM facultymember ".
    "WHERE password='$password' AND ID='$ID'", $connection);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

if(false != $row){ // user info exists/correct
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $row['ID'];
    if('1' == $row['pin']) { //not admin    
        header("location: homeFM.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
        die;
    } else { //admin
        header("location: homeA.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
        die;
    }
} else { //login doesn't exist
    $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}

mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
```

And that should work for you, hopefully the comments explain it. If it doesn't work, let me know, but it should according to the info you provided.

That being said....

I hope that your passwords are hashed, the input is sanitized, and that you look in to using `PDO` or `MySQLi` classes instead of the old deprecated `mysql_` functions.

As a side note `session_start();` is needed to start a session, not just assigning a variable within the super-global.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but it didn't work actually

Comment: Then I need more information to help. Can you give some actual data from the database? When you say "it doesn't work" what do you mean?

Comment: the page isn't working at all

Comment: (I did remove the extra curly brace for my answer, you would need to put it back in for your code.)

Comment: yes i did that, still the page isn't working

Comment: No one can help you based on "it isn't working" You need to give more information than that for anyone helping to go on.

Comment: sorry, the page is working but the page homeFM.php shows for both admin and user

Comment: Have you checked the database to make sure admin has a `0` for their `pin` field?

Comment: yes I'm pretty sure of this

Comment: Might want to re-check your database, as that is the only thing that can be going wrong according to what you have said. ^^

Comment: I just checked it, it's 1 for user and 0 for admin, Thank you Jon anyway

Comment: After `mysql_fetch_assoc`, do a `var_dump($row); die;` and see what it shows.

Comment: sorry but I'm a beginner and I don't know how to write it

Comment: Right after `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);` put a new line with `var_dump($row);die;`

Comment: array(3) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1111" ["password"]=> string(5) "12345" ["pin"]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: Is that for the user or admin? Try it with the admin one and see what you get.

Comment: the above is for user, this for admin: array(3) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "2222" ["password"]=> string(4) "1212" ["pin"]=> string(1) "0" }

Comment: Updated my answer to remove unneeded middle variable, and type of comparison.  Try it again?

Comment: Thaaaaaaaank you *_*

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: There is 1 more closing curly braces '}' found
```

I'm guessing it is the last curly brace that needs removing

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ID, password FROM facultymember  WHERE password='".$password."' AND ID=".$ID, $connection);

$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT pin FROM facultymember WHERE password='".$password."' AND ID=".$ID, $connection);
```

Your querys had weird concatenation

Comment: this brace if for other statement above which i didn't copy

Comment: your edit caused a problem, the page isn't working anymore

Comment: Oops my mistake should work now